# Hide a specific tag a with display name via CSS

Tags: css

I need to hide this tag based on `Your text` via CSS

```
<a href="/workflow/Lists/users1/AllItems.aspx" >Your text</a>
```

I tried this one that working properly

```
a[href='/workflow/Lists/users1/AllItems.aspx']{ display: none; }
```

But I need with the display name within `a Tag`

Is it applicable ?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text
I believe that this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1520501/2457045 would be a good solution for you.

Comment: Thanks @HenriqueArthur for your help but I need it with css for  the dispaly name within a Tag is it applicable via css ?

Comment: Read the question that I sent to you. As said in there, there's no way to do this with CSS because there's no selector to match the content of the tag (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Comment: You can use something like data-text as an attribute in your anchor tag. Like this: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/f8qpw6w6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="/workflow/Lists/users1/AllItems.aspx"  class="text1">Your text</a>
.text1

{ display: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Michał for your help but I need it with css for  the dispaly name within a Tag is it applicable via css ?

Comment: Make a class to your <a href=".." class="text1">
and then in CSS .text1 {display: none;}